# Oracle modify column not allowed because of the length of value

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to modify a column in my table, decreasing its length from 10 to 1:

```
alter table mytable
modify mycolumn varchar2(1)
```

but this returns the following error:

> 1441. 00000 -  "cannot decrease column length because some value is too big"

I have deleted the rows that I thought they were causing the problem:

```
delete from mytable
where length(mycolumn) > 1
```

and then

```
select count(*) from mytable
where length(mycolumn) > 1
```

returns `0`

But when I try to run the alter modify statement I get again the same error message.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `alter table mytable modify mycolumn varchar2(1 char)`

Comment: worked. is it an oracle bug?

Comment: oh  i see. it was trying to alter in bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `varchar2(1)` is treated as varchar with the length of 1 **byte**. However, some encodings require more than 1 byte to store a character (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.). Probably there's a character in the table that requires more than one byte, so the size of `varchar2(1)` is simply not enough.

`varchar2(1 char)` forces Oracle count the size in characters, not bytes, so that fixes the issue.

Comment: Default length semantics is defined by session parameter `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` (which is `BYTE` by default). You can modify it for your session.